Magento2.4.6: why Js files are not removing from homepage using layout?
I'm using Porto Theme as parent theme and in my child theme I'm using
layout to remove any unused JS and CSS from different pages. But I'm stuck at JS which is not removed anywhere on any page. this is the code and attached a screenshot of the network tab.

app/design/frontend/vendor/module/Magento_Theme/layout/cms_index_index.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <remove src="Magento_Theme::js/inputMask.js"/>
        <remove src="mage/calendar.css"/>
    </head>
</page>


whats the reason, why its not getting removed?

Please create a default_head_blocks.xml file under Magento_Theme\layout in your child theme Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml
Now paste this code
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
          <remove src="Magento_Theme::js/inputMask.js"/>
          <remove src="mage/calendar.css"/>
    </head>
</page>

After then run this command php bin/magento c:f

this method doesn't work when project js files are getting used through the require js dependency.
